# Reverse the position of search box and entry box in a datatable

Tags: r, dt

I would like to to reverse the positions of the 'number of entries' and 'search box' at the top of the data table, so that the search box appears on the left and entries on the right. Is this somehow possible?

```
library(DT)
datatable(iris)
```

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is a minimal example using `float`

This should work for this example but make sure you check `id` for the search and entry boxes in your shiny app. In this example they are `#DataTables_Table_0_length` and `#DataTables_Table_0_filter`.

In Chrome, if you right click and click on Inspect then scroll down to find the parts that you are after.

[image]

[image]

```
library(DT)
library(shiny)

ui <- fluidPage(

  tags$head(
    tags$style(
      HTML(
        "#DataTables_Table_0_length {
          float: right
        }
        #DataTables_Table_0_filter {
          float: left
        }
        "
      ))),

  h2("The mtcars data"),
  DT::dataTableOutput("mytable")
)

server <- function(input, output) {
  output$mytable = DT::renderDataTable({
    mtcars
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: how can I find the ids?

Comment: In Chrome, right click and click `Inspect` then you can see the `Elements`.